# Hibernate Query Compare Date (Max. 10 months in past)

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I'm trying to find out if the date is within 10 months. If not the record should be ignored! The solution needs to work with HQL. I already tried multiple queries:

**This one is working but not what I want:**

```
session.createQuery("FROM Application WHERE id="+id+" AND date < current_date()").getResultList();
```

**Something is null here:**

```
session.createQuery("FROM Application WHERE id="+id+" AND month(date) + (10-month(current_date()) < month(current_date())").getResultList();
```

**"Interval" is unknown:**

```
session.createQuery("FROM Application WHERE id="+id+" AND DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 10 MONTH) < date").getResultList();
```

**"Months" is unknown:**

```
session.createQuery("FROM Application WHERE id="+id+" AND current_date()-10 month < date+").getResultList();
```

I don't have more ideas how to solve this problem. Hopefully someone can help me here.

Thanks!

Comment: please tag your question with the DB you are using

Comment: I added the tag. I am using MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you try this...

```
    static SimpleDateFormat datetimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    date.add(Calendar.MONTH, -10);
    Date date1=date.getTime();
    String newdate=datetimeFormat.format(date1);

   Query query=session.createQuery("FROM Application a WHERE a.id="+id+" AND a.date <" + "'"+newdate+"'");

   System.out.println(query.list().size());
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. But your code gives me this error: HTTP Status 500 - org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '"' [FROM com.XXX.XXX.application.Application a WHERE a.id=7 AND a.date

Comment: check your entity class attribute whether they are same as i mentioned eg: id and date. Check if you need to fomat the date ('yyyy-MM-dd'). The above code definitely work

Comment: I checked them again and they are right. But it looks like there is a problem with the "Calendar"...

Comment: i have edited the code now it is fully tested so this should definitely work now

Comment: Thank you! I also came to the same solution as your last edit.